# Updating a cookie value with js-cookie?

Tags: javascript, cookies, js-cookie

This might be a dumb question but does the `Cookies.set("param","value")` update the value of the cookie.

So let just say for example that I have a cookie called param and the value is set to 1. Now if I have some kind of event and have `Cookies.set("param","2")`. Does that just change the value of the original cookie or will it set a new one?

Thanks

Comment: The cookie would be overridden. But the better question is why you need an API to handle cookies. Raw JavaScript can set cookies in a single line of code...

Comment: It is mostly because I am using it for an age gate and approximate geolocation. We are also on a time constraint that makes this a quicker solution.